# install ubuntu 14.04 server using kernel 3.13.0-24

Tags: server

I am running IBM Domino and there is a bug in the current 14.04 release that is not in the release using kernel 3.13.0-24. Where do I find the iso that uses this kernel so that I can upgrade my 13.10 server to 14.04 and not break my Domino server?

Comment: If you upgrade using the `do-release-upgrade` tool, you'll get the current version of the kernel available: 3.13.0.35.42

Answer (score 0):

You can't really download a disc image that will get you 14.04 with the 13.10 kernel.

It's certainly possible to run Ubuntu with a different kernel, though. You can try upgrading to 14.04, but removing the new kernel. Keep the old kernel and don't upgrade it. If you don't run into dependency issues with this, there could still be unexpected problems due to running a different kernel version than expected.

Comment: I have found the 14.04 server iso with the 3.13.0-24 generic which was released on 04/16/2014. and will be doing the upgrade with it next weekend. I was not implying that I wanted to use a 13.10 kernel after installing 14.04.